# Integrating Oracle Webcenter Interaction with Oracle Webcenter Spaces

Tags: oracle, webcenter, plumtree

This is a re-post of a question I posted in the Oracle OTN forum, but haven't yet had a response from - I suppose that doesn't bode too well - but I thought I'd try here.

I'm wondering if anyone has tried integrating Webcenter collaboration (i.e. the former Plumtree/BEA Aqualogic collaboration tools) with Webcenter Spaces?

To give a bit of background, I'm planning the migration of a Plumtree installation to Webcenter Spaces but my initial investigation work suggests that the diary and list functionality in Spaces does not have some of the key requirements highlighted by the current userbase as out-of-the-box functionality, e.g. the gantt chart views, sub tasks, recurring diary events, combined community views of projects, etc.

My thought is that Spaces could consume the services available through collaboration as portlets and link out directly to the project explorer in the same way that WCI does - so effectively just replacing the front-end?

Myself and my colleagues are going to investigate further anyway, but if anyone has experience in this area any comments would be much appreciated.

Thanks.